# com.google.android.maps not available

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and I'm using IntelliJ to develop. I'm going through various tutorials, etc and now I'm trying to run/compile Wrox project that uses com.google.android.maps

IntelliJ wouldn't compile, it complains that this package does not exist.

How do I add it to project? I have everything downloaded in ADT. I was able to run all other projects no problem. What should I look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the Google APIs instead of Android  - in IntelliJ, File-Project Structure SDKs and select Google APIs in Build Target.

Answer (score 0):

Are you targetting the correct Android-jar? You'd want the one with the Google API:s for maps to work. Also make sure you're including the correct permission in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

And after installing the google api and setting up a project based on the correct api, don't forget the uses-libary tag in the manifest:

```
<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:debuggable="true">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```